# How do I prevent the height of li change when increasing its border to 2px from 1px?

Tags: html, css

Every time when the mouse is over the box, its border needs to increase from `1px` to `2px`. But it would make all the content below the `li:hover` moving one pixel downwards.

How do I prevent this? Is there a pure CSS solution?

Thanks,

```js
$('li').on('mouseover', function(){$(this).addClass('li-hover')});

$('li').on('mouseout', function(){$(this).removeClass('li-hover')});
```

```css
li {border:1px solid black; margin-bottom:9px}

.li-hover {border:2px solid black}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
<li>bar1</li>
<li>bar2</li>
<li>bar3<br>break line</li>
<li>bar4</li>
<li>bar5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this using `outline` instead of `border`, as `outline` does not affect the height of the element (whereas `border` is resizing the box).

In addition, I'd suggest using the `:hover` in css rather than explicitly setting a class on `hover`, so instead of `.li-hover`, use `li:hover`:

```css
li {outline:1px solid black; margin-bottom:9px}

li:hover {outline:2px solid black}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
<li>bar1</li>
<li>bar2</li>
<li>bar3<br>break line</li>
<li>bar4</li>
<li>bar5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I love this but outline doesn’t have a border-radius thing

Answer (score 2):

I would wrap the initial text and put a border on that - that way you can start with a transparent border on the li:

```js
$('li').on('mouseover', function() {
  $(this).addClass('li-hover')
});

$('li').on('mouseout', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('li-hover')
});
```

```css
li {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  margin-bottom: 9px
}

li > span {
  display:block;
  border: 1px solid black; 
}

.li-hover {
  border-color: black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><span>bar1</span></li>
  <li><span>bar2</span></li>
  <li><span>bar3<br>break line</span></li>
  <li><span>bar4</span></li>
  <li><span>bar5</span></li>
</ul>
```

If you can't add an extra span, you could use a box-shadow (which also works with border radius):

```css
li {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  border-radius:5px;
}

li:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>bar1</li>
  <li>bar2</li>
  <li>bar3<br>break line</li>
  <li>bar4</li>
  <li>bar5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use outline then try this:

```
.li-hover {border:2px solid black; margin-bottom: 7px;}
```

```js
$('li').on('mouseover', function(){$(this).addClass('li-hover')});

$('li').on('mouseout', function(){$(this).removeClass('li-hover')});
```

```css
li {border:1px solid black; margin-bottom:9px}

.li-hover {border:2px solid black; margin-bottom: 7px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>bar1</li>
<li>bar2</li>
<li>bar3<br>break line</li>
<li>bar4</li>
<li>bar5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sounds practical

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('li').on('mouseover', function() {
  $(this).addClass('li-hover')
});
$('li').on('mouseout', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('li-hover')
});
```

```css
li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 9px
}

li:hover {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

span {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}

span:hover {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><span>bar1</span></li>
  <li><span>bar2</span></li>
  <li><span>bar3<br>break line</span></li>
  <li><span>bar4</span></li>
  <li><span>bar5</span></li>
</ul>
```